# iOSを用いてService Workerをローカル環境でテストしてみたい。

Tags: javascript, npm

Node.jsのbrowser-syncを用いて動作しようとしたところ

server.js

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");
browserSync({
  server: "/public",
  https: true,
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"

  },
  "https": true,
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.5"
  }
}
```

下記のような構成にしました。
しかしながら証明書がオレオレ証明書なため、ServiceWorkerが動作しません
どうにかローカルの環境でSSLを発行する手段は無いものでしょうか？

Comment: 目的や方法が違うかもしれませんが、この記事[PWA 入門 〜iOS SafariでPWAを体験するまで〜 2018年6月版](https://qiita.com/umamichi/items/0e2b4b1c578e7335ba20)とか、この記事[Apple Safari Ships Service Worker and Progressive Web App (PWA) Support on iOS 11.3](https://love2dev.com/blog/apple-shipps-service-workers/)が参考になるかも。

Answer (score 0):

> どうにかローカルの環境でSSLを発行する手段は無いものでしょうか？

iOS端末ごとにインストールが必要になりますが、iOSにオレオレ証明書を信頼させる方法はどうでしょうか。

手順は以下です。

1. サーバのオレオレ証明書(例: server.crt)をメール等によりiOS側に送付
2. iOS側で、送付されたオレオレ証明書を開き、インストール
3. iOS側で、「設定」-「一般」-「情報」-「証明書信頼設定」(「情報」の一番下にある)を開く
4. 「証明書信頼設定」にインストールした証明書がスイッチ`OFF`の状態で表示されるので、スイッチ`ON`に設定する

テスト用端末にオレオレ証明書をインストールすればテストを実施できると思います。

---

参考:
[How to deploy Securly SSL certificate to iOS?](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206978437-How-to-deploy-Securly-SSL-certificate-to-iOS-)

Comment: お返事いただき大変ありがとうございます。

現在browserSyncを用いてSSLの取得方法を模索中ですが、可能でしたらBAとさせていただきますのでお待たせするとは思います。

しかしながら手順の分かりやすい返答ありがたいです。